# How to Do a Join using Hibernate between two Entities (unrelated Entities)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two entites in Java: Screen and FavoriteScreen,

Screen Attributes: 
    screenId
    owner, ...

FavoriteScreen: 
    screenId
    Screen : the Entity Itself
    and other fields related to other tables.

My problem is that I want to get All the screens that are favorite using Hibernate  Join.
I solved the problem with an SQL statement like this one:

select * from the dashboard where id in (select id from the favorite dashboard)

is there any way to solve it using Hibernate.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904573/hibernate-left-outer-join)

Comment: It is not the same conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is you query:

`select * from the Screen where id in (select screen_id from the FavoriteScreen)`

if so you can add OneToOne relationship between FavoriteScreen and Screen. Then fetch Screen from FavoriteScreen.

```
@Entity
public class FavoriteScreen {
   ... attributes...

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "screen_id")
   Screen screen
}
```

It will create one to one association between Screen and FavoriteScreen.
and you can fetch Screen using.

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select FS.screen From FavoriteScreen FS ").getResultList()
```